# How to intercept on update command UI message CN_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI

Tags: c++, mfc

I have special class for holding groups of data. The class consists of core functionality and gui functionality. I use particular group method to show context menus and execute menu commands. I intercept `WM_COMAND` easy in `PreTranslateMessage`, but I have trouble with `update command ui` message. I use `CN_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`. It doesn't even come to `PreTranslateMessage` of the `CMDIFrameWndEx` class. At the same time it has to come there because menu menu also uses this message.
Using `control range` message handler is not an option because identifier may be messed up and everything will not work.

How can I intercept the message to handle `on update command ui`?

Secondary walk around is make menu items work without `on update command ui`. How can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK a lot of the MFC UI updating for non-menu items (e.g. toolbar buttons) is handled by the framework in the `WM_IDLE` processing at the `CWinApp` level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of deeper debug I have found that this message is coming into `OnCmdMsg` of `CCmdTarget`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essk9ab2.aspx), ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI is processed when WM_INITMENUPOPUP message is generated. So I think you must try to look for WM_INITMENUPOPUP message in your PreTranslateMessage.